# Is there a Layer 2 protocol when using an Ethernet hub?

Tags: networking, network-adapter

When I plug the LAN port of a computer to a 10BaseT hub (not switch), is there a Layer 2 driver in play?

If I now plug the same cable to an Ethernet switch, does the driver stack change?

Comment: No, is the simple answer to both questions, unless for the second you are running bridging software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an Ethernet host always deals with Ethernet layer-2 among other things.

Ethernet L2 operates between hosts – *both* hubs and switches are (mostly) transparent at L2, and nothing changes in a host's operation between being connected to a hub, vs a switch, vs a direct connection to another host.